# List comprehension to dictionary with multiple commands (Python, curser.execute)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I work with Python 3.6.
I have connected to Hive using Pyhive and my cursor is cur.

Objective:
Build a databases - tables map in a dictionary: 
dbname1 : list of tables within this db.

I have built it using for loop but I would like to transfer it to a dictionary comprehension please tell me what is wrong with my dict comprehension:

```
lst = extract_dbs_tbls(cur, s = 'show databases')

map_tbl_db = {}

for i in lst:
    cur.execute("use %s" % i)
    map_tbl_db['i'] = extract_dbs_tbls(cur, 'show tables')
```

Note: lst is a list of databases names like `['default', 'dwh', ...]`

Basically what I want is the following dict comprehension:

```
{i:j for i in lst cur.execute('use %i' % i) j = extract_dbs_tbls(cur, s = 'show tables')}
```

Where extract_dbs_tbls:

```
def extract_dbs_tbls(cur, s = 'show tables'):

    "Return list of dbs / tables. Note: use before 'use db_name'."

    cur.execute(s)
    lst = cur.fetchall()

    return [j[0] for j in lst];
```

Comment: I don't think this is a valid way to do dict compression, `{i:j for i in lst}` is valid Python, but `cur.execute('use %i' % i) j = extract_dbs_tbls(cur, s = 'show tables')` after `lst` will break your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call `cur.execute` as additional operation in list comprehension you can use some dummy var and list (`cur.execute` is placed in list `[ ]` to create iterable with one element just to call contained function) that will not be used in result dict. And your `j` var is not needed and replaced by in place calling `extract_dbs_tbls`:

```
{i: extract_dbs_tbls(cur, s = 'show tables')
 for i in lst
 for dummy in [cur.execute('use %i' % i)]}
```

above is equivalent to your loop:

```
map_tbl_db = {}
for i in lst:
    cur.execute("use %s" % i)
    map_tbl_db[i] = extract_dbs_tbls(cur, 'show tables')
```

Comment: ndpu, why [cur.execute('use %i' % i)]?
I mean what the second for actually does?

Comment: @steves second `for` needed to call `cur.execute`

Comment: Is there any way to combine the cur.execute to combine use and show tables?

Comment: It is quite tricky. In that case the original seems to me more readable. I would use _ instead of dummy.

Comment: @steves `cur.execute` is calling (1 time) to each iteration of `i` loop... `extract_dbs_tbls` get new `cur` on each iteration of `i`, just like in your function...